# Filtering data only if criteria is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to configure this query that I have but I can't think of a way to do it. My query is below:

```
select per.Forenames, per.Surname, p.Identifier2
from patient p
join Person per on per.PersonID = p.PersonID
where not exists (select 1
              from Episode e
              where e.PatientID = p.PatientID and
                    e.EpisodeTypeID in ('FCB9EAA0-C814-413E-A5FC-48547EF973B7',
                                        'E422A8FA-839B-44AD-9A60-6973FEF39361',
                                        '08929D40-863E-4D46-94BD-B4DF9352A855',
                                        'C8BE80C4-AA0A-41ED-A44C-BCBE2CC980C0',
                                        '8C3848C7-8621-43CF-A58D-D4A6ED4DC166',
                                        'C244B01A-E9DD-4BF4-B336-1479A5A7C88D',
                                        '632FAC1E-6B04-4A69-8BF2-0C2E2B0AD8AB'
                                       ) and

                    e.EpisodeDate between '2016-04-01' and '2016-12-15'

              )
and p.PatientStatus = 'Current'
group by p.Identifier2, per.Forenames, per.Surname
```

So what this query is doing is finding certain people only if they haven't attended the specified episode types. Now what I want to do, is filter this even further. I want to make it so that if they have *have attended* the episode type with the ID '9254B31D-A304-498C-ADE4-F4003997C8FA' then they should still appear on this list, but *only* if their attended status is set to 'Yes'. Otherwise I don't want them to show up.

Where can I add this filter?

Comment: Add those condition in `inner query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of logic is easier to do using `group by` and `having`:

```
select per.Forenames, per.Surname, p.Identifier2
from patient p join
     Person per
     on per.PersonID = p.PersonID join
     Episode e
     on e.PatientID = p.PatientID
group by per.Forenames, per.Surname, p.Identifier2
having sum(case when e.EpisodeTypeID in ('FCB9EAA0-C814-413E-A5FC-48547EF973B7',
                                         'E422A8FA-839B-44AD-9A60-6973FEF39361',
                                         '08929D40-863E-4D46-94BD-B4DF9352A855',
                                         'C8BE80C4-AA0A-41ED-A44C-BCBE2CC980C0',
                                         '8C3848C7-8621-43CF-A58D-D4A6ED4DC166',
                                         'C244B01A-E9DD-4BF4-B336-1479A5A7C88D',
                                         '632FAC1E-6B04-4A69-8BF2-0C2E2B0AD8AB'
                                        ) and
                    e.EpisodeDate between '2016-04-01' and '2016-12-15'
                then 1 else 0
            end) = 0 and
          sum(case when e.EpisodeTypeId = '9254B31D-A304-498C-ADE4-F4003997C8FA' and
                        e.AttendedStatus <> 'Yes'  -- assumes AttendedStatus is not NULL
                   then 1 else 0
              end) = 0;
```

Each `sum()` expression counts the number of matches for the conditions

Comment: Thanks Gordon, as helpful as always. Worked exactly as I needed it to.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add another condition for `and exists` if you want an additional condition above and beyond the existing conditions like this:

```
select per.Forenames, per.Surname, p.Identifier2
from patient p
...
and p.PatientStatus = 'Current'
and exists (
    select 1
    from Episode e1
    where e1.PatientID = p.PatientID
    and e1.EpisodeTypeID = '9254B31D-A304-498C-ADE4-F4003997C8FA'
    and e1.AttendedStatus = 'Yes'
    )
group by ...
```